# Transpose the Data

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(VAR1 = c("A",  "A",    "A",    "A",    "A",    "A",    "B",    "B",    "B",            
                              "B",  "B",    "B",    "C",    "C",    "C",    "C",    "C",    "C",            
                              "D",  "D",    "D",    "D",    "D",    "D",    "E",    "E",    "E",    "E",    "E",    "E"), 
                     VAR2 = c("A1", "A1",   "A1",   "A2",   "A2",   "A2",   "B1",   "B1",   "B1",           
                              "B2", "B2",   "B2",   "C1",   "C1",   "C1",   "C2",   "C2",   "C2",           
                              "D1", "D1",   "D1",   "D2",   "D2",   "D2",   "E1",   "E1",   "E1",   "E2",   "E2","E2"),
                     VAR3 = c("alpha",  "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",
                              "beta",   "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta",
                              "gamma",  "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma",    "alpha",    "beta", "gamma"),
                     VALUE = c(56,  38, 83, 29, 73, 75, 99, 88, 30, 58,
                               97,  42, 64, 67, 45, 99, 62, 65, 7,  40,
                               49,  62, 82, 63, 65, 40, 45, 29, 73, 51))
```

I want to transpose the data in wide format, where `VAR1` & `VAR2` are columns, values of `VAR3` will be 3 extra columns and `VALUE` column will be populated as values in this structure.

My question is how to do it using tidyverse & data.table::dcast? Which will be more efficient if the data size is very large, say 2 GB in raw form (my RAM size is 8 GB)?

Thanks!

Comment: tidyr/tidyverse way will be simply `mydata %>% spread(VAR3,VALUE)`

Comment: @moody: thanks for your quick reply. In 'tidyr' why didn't you consider other 2 vars for spread?

Comment: and `data.table::dcast` when used on regular data.frames is a wrapper around `reshape2::dcast`, `reshape2` being pretty much the ancestor of `tidyr`

Comment: by default unmentioned columns are the grouping columns in `spread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dcast()` from `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

dcast(mydata,
      VAR1 + VAR2 ~ VAR3,
      value.var = "VALUE")
```

Which will return

```
   VAR1 VAR2 alpha beta gamma
1     A   A1    56   38    83
2     A   A2    29   73    75
3     B   B1    99   88    30
4     B   B2    58   97    42
5     C   C1    64   67    45
6     C   C2    99   62    65
7     D   D1     7   40    49
8     D   D2    62   82    63
9     E   E1    65   40    45
10    E   E2    29   73    51
```

Comment: I am glad I could be of help!